# How to find the element's x center coordinates and related window offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, coordinates, center, offset

i would like to retrieve the element offset starting from his own x center coordinates.

how can i do it?

Actually i can find the window offset of an element but it retrieves the coordinates from the border of the element like this:

```
var _position = $(this).offset();
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to get, the position of the middle of your element instead of its most left-top? Also, $position isn't a right syntax, if so just add width/2 to the X and height/2 to the height and you're good.

Comment: @ShaiMishali That is the right syntax. It works perfectly. It only isn't the convention to name variables like that in JavaScript.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You have to use `offset()` to get the top and left position, then add half of the `height()` and `width()` values to them. That gives the center coordinates.

```
var $this = $(this);
var offset = $this.offset();
var width = $this.width();
var height = $this.height();

var centerX = offset.left + width / 2;
var centerY = offset.top + height / 2;
```

If you need to consider the padding property in your calculations, use the following:

```
var width = $this.outerWidth();
var height = $this.outerHeight();
```

Comment: do you know if the width() takes care of padding css rule?

Comment: The `padding` property is not included. If you want to also include the padding, use `.outerWidth()`.

Answer (score 23):

This can now be done through native Javascript also:

```
let centerX = targetNode.offsetLeft + targetNode.offsetWidth / 2;
let centerY = targetNode.offsetTop + targetNode.offsetHeight / 2;
```

where targetNode is the element you want to get its center coordinates.

Comment: This only figures out the center relative to the targetNode's OffsetParent.  Any parent element (all the way up the tree) with positioning other than static (the default) will effect this.

Comment: this method returns undefined in svg objects