# Is it possible to get the color behind a div thats placed on top of a background image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If you have a background image that covers the entire body of an HTML page, and you have the body split up into several divs (Think like a grid) is it possible to tell what the color is behind the center point of the div?

[image: The blue grid is divs. The Dots represent the center point of the div and what color I want to find out about]

In this image the blue grid represents 'divs'. the Dots represent the  center point of the div and color I want to find out about.

Answer (score 2):

i found a solution with the help of 2 answers ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3236129/6617849), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3277417/6617849)).

i created 2 divs:

1 - to use the cover image.

2 - a container for the grid.

the image-div lays in front of the grid-container.
when you click on the image, it will save the coordinates of the clicked point and change the z-index of the image-div to be at the back.

than simulate a click on the document (the grid container is in front now) using the same coordinates, to get the css property.

finally switch the z-index of the image-div to be displayed in the front again.

please run the following code in full window or see it in the provided [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gababa/cq803fhv/32/).

```js
var posX, posY;
    $("#cover").click(function(e){
    
    //get cursor coordinates
    posX = e.pageX;
    posY = e.pageY;
    
    //push cover image to the back of the view
    $(this).css("z-index",-1);
    
    //simulate click with same coordinates on grid-container
    document.elementFromPoint(posX, posY).click();
    
    //switch cover image back to the front of the view
    $(this).css("z-index",2);
    });
    
    //get bgColor and use it
    $(".grid-item").click(function(){
    var bgColor = $(this).css("background-color");
    //use bgColor as you like
    $("#result").css("background-color",bgColor);
    })
```

```css
#cover, .grid-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    }
    #cover {
    z-index: 2;
    background-image: url('https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/4.sm.jpg');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    }

    .grid-container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    }

    .grid-item {
      padding: 20px;
      font-size: 40px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    #grid-item-1 { background-color: #00061e; }
    #grid-item-2 { background-color: #394266; }
    #grid-item-3 { background-color: #61a7d3; }
    #grid-item-4 { background-color: #db2f1c; }
    #grid-item-5 { background-color: #8b8f91; }
    #grid-item-6 { background-color: #ce171d; }
    #grid-item-7 { background-color: #92ed5a; }
    #grid-item-8 { background-color: #db25db; }
    #grid-item-9 { background-color: #fcf00b; }
    span { 
    position:absolute;
    top:85%;
    }
    #result {
     width:50px;
     height:50px;
     left:200px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div>

    <div id="cover"></div>

     <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="grid-item" id="grid-item-1">1</div>
      <div class="grid-item" id="grid-item-2">2</div>
      <div class="grid-item" id="grid-item-3">3</div>
      <div class="grid-item" id="grid-item-4">4</div>
      <div class="grid-item" id="grid-item-5">5</div>
      <div class="grid-item" id="grid-item-6">6</div>
      <div class="grid-item" id="grid-item-7">7</div>
      <div class="grid-item" id="grid-item-8">8</div>
      <div class="grid-item" id="grid-item-9">9</div>
    </div> 

    </div>

    <span>background-color result:</span>
    <span id="result"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you first need to find out the coordinate of the center of each child div, see:
[How to find the element's x center coordinates and related window offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027875/how-to-find-the-elements-x-center-coordinates-and-related-window-offset) 
after that you need the color of background image of parent div in that position, see :
[Get pixelcolor of CSS Background Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31008261/get-pixelcolor-of-css-background-image)